# Swift-How do I add Tab Bar AND Navigation Bar to a single view controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, view, uinavigationbar

Using XCode, and either through Code or through the Storyboard, can someone please explain to me how to add both a Tab Bar and Nav Bar to my view controller while keeping both visible?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Provide what you have tried so far so others can better help you.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In your Storyboard, you should drag out a Tab Bar Controller and use that as the initial view controller. Then, you should embed each of the view controllers attached to the Tab Bar Controller inside Navigation Controllers (Editor menu: Embed In > Navigation Controller). Afterward, your Storyboard should look something like this:

[image]

The tab bar controller holds a tab bar and will manage switching between the other views attached to it, while the navigation controllers will place Navigation Bars at the top of each tab and help you manage navigation within the tab.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, thank you so much.
You wouldn't believe how hard it was to find such a simple and elegant answer like this.

Comment: that's perfect !

Answer (score 11):

[image: screenshot]

I am assuming you want something like this. Here is how I did it in Interface Builder:

1. Click your view controller.
2. `Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller`
3. Reselect your view controller.
4. `Editor -> Embed In -> Tab Bar Controller`
5. Select the Navigation Controller
6. Check the box next to `Is Initial View Controller`

Hope this helps!

Comment: With this you have the same navigation bar for both view controllers.

Comment: True, and if you need them to be different, I would recommend [Ronald Martin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31549190/4099162). In an application I was creating, I had several custom attributes on my navbar that were a pain to re-create, and I found it easier to just change the title of the nav. To each their own

Comment: Does there anyway to set title to NavigationItem?

Comment: my app has start with one page and then push to the tab bar controller so I embed In first page to navigation Bar But when in the tab Bar I click to go to another page I can't see the navigation Bar

Comment: @72A12F4E How do I do this programmatically