# Customize navigationBar in Swift UI

Tags: swiftui

I am new in swift ui. I want to put image button on the side of the NavigationBar title.
I want to be able to click the user image and navigate to another view. How?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having Tab bar and Navigationbar in the same View in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65955184/having-tab-bar-and-navigationbar-in-the-same-view-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `navigationBarItems` for putting image to navigation bar and you should add `NavigationLink` to that image. For center the title you need to set navigation bar title's `displayMode` to `.inline` or you can use new [Toolbar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/toolbar(content:)-7vdkx) api

---

```
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Text("Welcome to Stack Overflow")
        .navigationBarTitle("Header", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarItems(leading: NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination")) {
          Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill")
            .font(.title)
        })
    }
  }
}
```

---

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: tnx so much for ur answer, when ı click the image icon, I want to pass other Swift UI, is it possible?

Comment: Please see my code,  `NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination")` does that.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using toolbar item.

I am adding `TapGesture` on image icon, and keeping it out of `navigation link`, as the image is not getting circular inside the `NavigationLink` in `ToolbarItemGroup`.

By leveraging `isActive` property of `NavigationLink` which monitors `onTap` state  we can determine either we want to push our view or not.

```
import SwiftUI

struct WeatherView: View {
    
    @State var onTap = false
    var borderColor: Color = Color("Black")
    
    var addProjectToolbarItem: some ToolbarContent {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
            
            NavigationLink(destination:Text("Welcome"), isActive: self.$onTap) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            
            
            Image("yourImage")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .onTapGesture {
                    onTap.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("First view")
            }
            .toolbar{
                addProjectToolbarItem
            }
            .navigationTitle("Header")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: very well, tnx so much . I want to vote this answer but need at least 15 reputation.